# How to force Google to not mind my location during search

Tags: google-search, localization

I look for information about Tour de Pologne, the problem is that I want to know what foreign services say about it. I want to watch their videos with their comments but because I live in Poland I get a few pages of Polish websites.

How to force Google to treat my search phrase as I would be in UK for example?

Answer (score 2):

Any VPN or Proxy will do the job. I usually use tunnelbear https://www.tunnelbear.com/ it's free and has quite nice UI. Else you can use online based proxies.

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching using https://encrypted.google.com or you can also use country specific google domain like, https://www.google.co.uk

Generally I found searching using the former method gives better results.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Chrome add on [Hola Unblocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hola-better-internet/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=en). This is a VPN proxy and will allow you to *pretend* that you are browsing from a different country that you can choose with the add on.

Comment: From http://adios-hola.org/: *Hola is harmful to the internet as a whole, and to its users in particular. You might know it as a free VPN or "unblocker", but in reality it operates like a poorly secured [botnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) - with serious consequences.*