# Google keeps redirecting me to a country domain

Tags: google-search

I installed a new OS and I added Google Chrome to it.  Now whenever I search for something it searches in `google.com.cy`. I do not want to keep searching there; I want it to search in `google.com`. For example if I search something in the Google Chrome Omnibox, after it searches the wanted result it searches in `google.com.cy`. If I click a new tab it brings me again Google in region. I want to prevent this.

Comment: I assume you actually live in Cyprus.

Comment: If you set Google to search from the .com domain, it will do so as long as you keep its cookies. As for the omnibox, you can change/customise the search engine used by Chrome from preferences.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to force Google to not mind my location during search](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66455/354)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google.com (not the Omnibox) to search, there are two ways to change the search settings:

1. Visit the [Google Preferences page](https://www.google.com/preferences#location) and set the location to wherever you want.
2. Search http://www.google.com/en instead of just Google.com

If you want to change your search location in the Omnibox then instead of pointing to Google.com in the search setting, use http://www.google.com/en, or whichever region you want.

Comment: @Tsunami: If this answer solved your problem, you should use the "checkmark" to "accept" this answer. This will act as a signpost to future readers. See more information in the [help center](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).